# Have these "calculus-based" consecutive summations been discovered yet?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the sum-of-powers series

$$S_i(n) = 1^i + 2^i + \cdots + n^i = \sum_{k=1}^n y_i(k) \quad\text{with}\; y_i(x)=x^i \tag{1}$$

For $i=1, 2, 3$, it turns out that we can write
$$\begin{align}
S_1(n) &= \frac{n+1}{n}\cdot\int_0^{n}y_1(x)\,dx \tag{2a}\\[4pt]
S_2(n) &= \frac{n+1}{n}\cdot\int_0^{n}y_2(x)\,dx \cdot \frac{y_2^\prime(n)+1}{y_2^\prime(n)} \tag{2b}\\[4pt]
S_3(n) &= \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^2\cdot\int_0^{n}y_3(x)\,dx \tag{2c}\\[4pt]
\end{align}$$
which simplify to the well-known formulas
$$\begin{align}
S_1(n) &= \frac12 n(n+1) \tag{3a}\\[4pt]
S_2(n) &= \frac16 n(n+1)(2n+1) \tag{3b}\\[4pt]
S_3(n) &= \frac14 n^2 (n + 1)^2 \tag{3c}\\[4pt]
\end{align}$$

The only thing is that I'm not quite sure *why* these relations can include derivatives and integrals and somehow even work at all - they were simply a result of an extremely tiresome trial and error process. And can this "template" be extended to any $S_i(n)$ series or even more unorthodox variants?

*Credits for the condensation and formatting of my answer goes to Blue (in the comments)*

Comment: The [Euler–Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Maclaurin_formula) might be of interest in this context, it describes the connection between the sum $\sum_{i=0}^n f(i)$ and the integral $\int_0^n f(x) dx$

Comment: @MartinR I just had a quick look and I think I might need to spend more time decrypting the logic, since the terminology is much more complex than I can possibly understand. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: By the way, the name for the general formula for these sums is called Faulhaber's formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Answer (score 3):

(Too long for a comment.) The reuse and ambiguity of symbols is a little confusing. I'd like to try to restate the problem.

---

Consider the sum-of-powers series

$$S_i(n) = 1^i + 2^i + \cdots + n^i = \sum_{k=1}^n y_i(k) \quad\text{with}\; y_i(x)=x^i \tag{1}$$

For $i=1, 2, 3$, it turns out that we can write
$$\begin{align}
S_1(n) &= \frac{n+1}{n}\cdot y_1^\prime(n)\cdot\int_0^{n}y_1(x)\,dx  \tag{2a}\\[4pt]
S_2(n) &= \frac{n+1}{n}\cdot \frac{y_2^\prime(n)+1}{y_2^\prime(n)}\cdot\int_0^{n}y_2(x)\,dx \tag{2b}\\[4pt]
S_3(n) &= \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^2\cdot\int_0^{n}y_3(x)\,dx \tag{2c}\\[4pt]
\end{align}$$
which simplify to the well-known formulas
$$\begin{align}
S_1(n) &= \frac12 n(n+1) \tag{3a}\\[4pt]
S_2(n) &= \frac16 n(n+1)(2n+1) \tag{3b}\\[4pt]
S_3(n) &= \frac14 n^2 (n + 1)^2 \tag{3c}
\end{align}$$
[Can this technique be extended? Is it new? etc, etc, etc]

---

Does this capture the intent of the question?

(BTW: I think you need to be a bit more explicit about why the relations in $(2)$ hold.)

Comment: Thank you Blue for restating my question much more simply - I'm new on this platform so am still learning how to use the syntax. Would you mind completing your edit for the bit that I've added, and I'll replace my text with yours. Is that okay? Thanks again!

Comment: Sure. I just noticed you added the case for cubes. Give me a minute.

Comment: You are amazing - thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks. :)  The update is complete. As noted, you really need to explain why the relations in $(2)$ hold.

Comment: That's the thing - I myself don't know how it works! All I did was make a table that included the sum at certain intervals, derivatives and integrals and then tried to find some proportionality between the terms, and it worked! That's why I'm so desperate to find out *why* it works at all.

Comment: @JainamShah: Your question is now clear on where you need help. As Martin suggests, Euler seems to have beaten you to this kind of analysis. (Euler has probably beaten *most* mathematicians to *something*.)

Comment: Gotta give it to him - Euler has not left a single stone unturned. Ah, I tried.